# How to remove jquery.ui accordion background

Tags: jquery-ui

I need to remove background for accordion i tried like this

```
.ui-accordion-content{
    border-style: none;
    background-color: none;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Didn't helped.

Full code [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kani339/fez62ksp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using following.

```
.ui-state-default 
{
    background-color: transparent !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
```